# How to handle similar actions in derived actors (inheritance)

Tags: architecture, polymorphism

I have a base class called `Attacker` that has a `update` method. The `update` method moves attacker through an array of waypoints as given below:

```
- (void) update:(ccTime)dt {
    if(state == kMove) {
        // code to move to next waypoint
        // on reaching the next waypoint, update the next waypoint variable
        // if the final waypoint is reached, then stop the movement of attacker
    }
}
```

So, the base class takes care of simple waypoint movement logic. Now I derive a few classes like `Rifleman`, `MachineGunner`, `Engineer` from the `Attacker` class.

Now I want each of the derived class to do a specific action on reaching the final waypoint. For eg., I want the Rifleman to change to attack stance, the machine gunner to deploy and setup his gun, the engineer to start constructing a defense.

How do I achieve this? My current idea is to check for final waypoint condition in the `update` method of each of the derived class and do the corresponding action.

```
- (void) update:(ccTime)dt {
    [super update:dt];
    if(state == kMove) {
        // if the final waypoint is reached, then do class specific action
    }
}
```

Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: If by "if the final waypoint is reached, then do class specific action" you mean just calling the "endFunction" then yes, polymorphism (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) will do the rest.

Comment: @mikidelux you should make an answer out of this

Comment: @mikidelux well if you think your comment is understandable enough, then you can just copy-paste it. But Jari Komppa has already given basically the same answer as of now.

Comment: I wrote the answer while you were discussing, sorry =)

Comment: @JariKomppa no probs :) u too answered me right... but i couldnt mark 2 right answers !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "if the final waypoint is reached, then do class specific action" you mean just calling the "endFunction" then yes, [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29)  will do the rest. That is, if you implement "endFunction" in every subclass or have a default one in the superclass.

Comment: is calling the `endFunction` in the `update` method of base class  enough? given the base class have an empty `endFunction`, which is overridden in the derived classes... am i right?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are saying it right (english is not my main language) but it should go like this:

SuperClass obj = new SubClass();

Then, when you call obj.endFunction(), the function in the subclass will be called instead of the superclass one (If there is an overriden endFunction in the subclass).

Comment: yes it works... thx :)

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution I can think of is to create a virtual function for whenArrivedAtFinalWaypoint, call that from update, and implement that for the child classes.

Comment: I am coding in objective-c which dont have virtual functions. But I suppose in obj-c method calls works the same, without any explicit virtual keyword.

Comment: @saiy2k yes, they do.

Comment: This. Just add a note to make it clear that it should be called from within the *baseclass* update.